# How to make a right aligned td to top in the mobile view?

Tags: html-table, media-queries, border-spacing

For **Desktop View** table look like this

| header 1 | Body 1 |
| --- | --- |

| header 2 | Body 2 |
| --- | --- |

| header 3 | Body 3 |
| --- | --- |

For **Mobile View** table look like this

| header 1 |
| --- |
| Body 1 |

| header 2 |
| --- |
| Body 2 |

| header 3 |
| --- |
| Body 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Here, before min width 1110px will consider as mobile view and after this will consider as desktop view:

```css
/* Mobile View*/
      table {
        border-spacing: 0 1rem;
      }

      td {
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      /* Desktop View*/
      @media screen and (min-width: 1110px) {
        td {
          display: table-cell;
        }
      }
```

```html
<!-- Expand snippet for desktop view -->
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Header 1</td>
        <td>Body 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Header 2</td>
        <td>Body 3</td>
        <td>Body 3-1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Header 3</td>
        <td>Body 3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```